# Tab navigation in content editable webview freezes the UI after closing a secondary window

Tags: webview, uwp, win-universal-app

Issue: In latest OS builds higher than 17763, UWP apps which uses a content editable webview freezes the UI in a particular scenario.

Prerequisites:

```
OS build version should be higher than 17763.
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
1. Launch the app and focus any textbox. 
2. Now keep tab pressed which will cause navigation across controls. Even if we keep the tab key pressed for a few seconds, it navigates between controls smoothly.
3. Then click new window button to launch a secondary view. Now close the secondary window.
4. Again, focus and textbox and keep tab key pressed. After a few seconds, UI freezes.
```

When trying the same in OS build version 17763, this issue doesn't occur. It works properly.

Sample repo - https://github.com/Kumara-Krishnan/WebViewFreeze

Sample video in both OS - https://workdrive.zohoexternal.com/external/35452a4cc8651089940a884cbac1cd143d514c39544fa47fdf70a62a374ab339

Comment: Yep, we could reproduce your problem, you could also post this with windows feed back hub app, or report bug in WInUI github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) box.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether this could be filed there or not. Thanks! I will raise an issue in github.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1227